# Runing Parent Process code only after suspending child

Tags: c, signals, fork, exec

I have a process P1. I am creating a child by fork ,and then exec inside the child's portion of the fork. I want to suspend the  child and then execute the rest of the parent code ONLY after the child is suspended . Any Idea how can i do that?

```
int pid=fork();
if(pid==0)
{ 
    //Do something in here
 } 
else
```

{
suspend the child and do something else ,only after the child is suspended
}

Comment: When do you want to suspend it?  If you want the child to wait to exec, you can either delay the fork, or block on a read from a pipe, or use any of several sync mechanisms.  If you want to suspend it at some arbitrary point after it has exec'd, you might as well wait for it to finish unless you have some way to synchronize with the exec'd job.

Comment: But I suppose you are wanting to send a SIGSTOP followed by a SIGCONT.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want to start the child and then immediatly stop it.But i want the paren't to continue only after the child is suspended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the simplest sync mechanism is a simple pipe.  If you want the child to wait before it execs, have it block on a read.  eg:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int p1[2];
        int c;
        if( pipe(p1)) {
                perror("pipe");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        switch( fork() ) {
        case -1:
                perror("fork");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        case 0:
                read(p1[0], &c, 1); /* wait on the parent */
                close(p1[0]);
                close(p1[1]);
                execlp("echo", "echo", "foo", NULL);
                perror("exec");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        default:
                puts("This will always print first");
                fflush(stdout);
                write(p1[1], &c, 1); /* tell the child to continue */
                close(p1[1]);
                close(p1[0]);
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you want the child to exec before you suspend it, you could try sending SIGSTOP and make it continue with SIGCONT, but there's really no point.  If you do that, you have no way of knowing when the child will stop and it may run to completion before you even send the SIGSTOP.  If you have some other external synchronization method (eg, the child is writing to the file system and you can monitor that), you should use that to make the child suspend itself.  Trying to use SIGSTOP/SIGCONT will have numerous race conditions that you'll need to deal with anyway.  The best bet is to delay `exec` with something like the above.

Comment: I want to start the child process and imediately suspend it and start the parent process after suspension

Comment: @georgestamatelis That's exactly what this does.  The child will block on a read until the parent writes data into the pipe.

Comment: @georgestamatelis No, don't say stupid.  It just takes experience to get comfortable with the idioms.